# messed with my partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, colors

i did something very stupid, and i messed with my partitions; i can access everything (already backed up my ubuntu partition) but i dont think i have enough space for backing up my other partition but it's not important.
The thing is, i have full access to the entire disk, i checked disk for errors (no problems reported) , but when booting up, it shows the image below.
I have already formatted the primary boot partition, and reinstalled ubuntu, but still the same image. I can boot from live cd, so it's not the graphics cards who messed up.

Basically, i tried to shrink the backup partition and grow the system's partition, but canceled it still on the shrink part, and i think it messed up in there, because after canceling, it still showed the free space from "shrink", which wasn't supposed ...i still grew the other partition, and i think that's where it all messed up ...

> ### Description
>
> Laptop: Samsung RV520
>
> > Graphics: Nvidia Geforce w/cuda 520m (if not mistaken, driver was nvidia 331-xx or something like that)

any suggestions are welcome ... :)

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/aln59s/8]

Comment: sorry, had to reboot to take the photo, it will be uploaded any minute now :P

Comment: it says i need 10 reputation to post images ... i'll upload link to it..

Comment: Seems a graphic card problem. The fact that the live dvd boots ok means nothing; it has often an older kernel and/or different boot parameters than the installed kernel. It normally also uses a safe but low-performance graphic driver, different from the one chosen by the installed system. Check the tens of question about "booting to a black screen", maybe someone apply; try booting with `nomodeset` option. And BTW, put the type of your PC/graphic card in the question.

Comment: @Rmano how can i boot with nomodeset if there is nothing before/while that colored screen happens?
i have completely formatted my disk, even changed disk type from msdos to gpt, still not working...

Comment: edited some bios settings, ehci(?) , uefi, and so on, then, booted from the usb i used to live cd, then, after i clicked on "install ubuntu" it booted and showed my name, so it did boot and not live cd, the akward thing in this is that i inserted usb, changed in bios to boot first from usb, live cd boot showed up, and it booted from disk ...
might be fine now, but i'll restore my stuff, to see if drivers and so on are restored and then i'll post the result 
Thank you :)

Comment: booted up after update, so far so good :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason why this didn't work, i erased the EFI partition, and i was trying to boot in UEFI mode, and (don't know why) even without UEFI boot, it woldn't boot, so i created an EFI partition, and now i can boot to ubuntu :P

before this, i tried to do something (which went wrong):
I had a backup.tgz, and extracted it to my disk, and some files could be overwritten, others couldn't (like hard links), and now, i'm stuck in a login loop -_-

trying to find a solution to this one, i'm a guy who only invents problems :P

another thing i found out:

after disabling UEFI in bios menu, my boot screen is messed up like the image i posted, and if it was enabled it only showed a purple screen (like ubuntu boot screen without the booting options).

it still doesn't show any option at boot screen, but now it's booting, so i changed the timeout for bootscreen and it boots fast ... i updated grub, it said it found my partitions with ubuntu, and memtest, etc, bit still doesn't show up on boot screen ...

the more you mess the more you know :P

Thank you all :)